# Selenium Python Using JavaScript to click link can i put it inside WebdriverWait

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using self.driver.execute_script Selenium in Python code to click a link. I am using time.sleep(20) otherwise the link won't get clicked. If i use time.sleep(15), the link won't get clicked. Strange it has to work for (20), page must be slow in loading. My automation scripts are on a VM.

Can i use Web driver Wait with driver.execute_script?  That will be a more efficient way.

I tried using WebDriverWait but i was getting errors.  I do not know the correct syntax.

My code is:

```
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators

def click_administration(self):
    time.sleep(20)
    admin_tab = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.Administration_tab)
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", admin_tab)
```

When i tried using WebDriverWait which shows errors, my code is:

```
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def click_administration(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
    admin_tab = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.Administration_tab)
    admin_tab_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((admin_tab)))
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", admin_tab)
```

The error is:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 85, in test_add_Project
        administration_page = data_dashboard_page.click_administration()
    File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\main_dashboard.py", line 80, in click_administration
        admin_tab_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((admin_tab)))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 67, in until
        value = method(self._driver)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 187, in __call__
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 73, in __call__
        return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 274, in _find_element
        return driver.find_element(*by)
    TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement
```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("ScriptGoesHere"))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have added it to my code like this.  Is this correct?  admin_tab = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.Administration_tab)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active === 0"))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", admin_tab)

Comment: Oh im sorry, It was just an example on how the syntax is to use execute script with WebDriverWait. Do you know why you have to wait for 20 seconds?

Comment: But to use WebDriverWait to execute a script I think you have to wait for something to be true (e.g the lambda expression who returns True when jQuery.active is 0).

Comment: I don't know why i have to wait 20 secs.  I think it is because the VM is very slow. The page takes long to complete the rendering.

Comment: I run the Webdriver wait code now.  It clicks the admin tab but then a Timeout error is thrown.    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Full error is: Traceback (most recent call last):  File C:\Webdriver\ClearCore \TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 85, in test_add_Project administration_page = data_dashboard_page.click_administration()
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\main_dashboard.py", line 70, in click_administration
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", admin_tab))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 76, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: